# What package replaces dkim-filter in 12.04?

Tags: server, 12.04, postfix, dkim

Previously, I was using the *dkim-filter* package in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for DKIM.

That package is no longer in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  What's the replacement or alternative?

opendkim, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SourceForge website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dkim-milter/):

> dkim-milter has been replaced by OpenDKIM

Indeed - the project has now states:

> As of 2011-12-13, this project is no longer under active development.

You are quite correct - [OpenDKIM](http://opendkim.org/docs.html) is its replacement - its a fork of dkim

More information about the OpenDKIM filter is in the [README file](http://opendkim.org/opendkim-README).

The [version in Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/opendkim) is slightly older then than the Project site - v2.5.0 vs 2.5.1  respectively.